# Radio button data couldn't be insert to mysql database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

Here is the insert code

```
$s1=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['s1']);


 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into applyleave(LeaveType,leave1,s1,FromDate,ToDate,duration,descr,sta,isRead,empId,empName,empEmail,employID) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        $stmt -> bindParam(1,$LeaveType);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(2,$typeofleave);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(3,$s1);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(4,$FromDate);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(5,$ToDate);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(6,$duration);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(7,$descr);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(8,$sta);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(9,$isRead);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(10,$empId);
                        // $stmt -> bindParam(11,$leaveSta);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(11,$empName);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(12,$empEmail);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(13,$employID);
                        $stmt -> execute();
```

Radio button code

```
 <div class="input-field col m6 s12" id="morning" style="display: none">
                                    <input type="radio" id="Morning" name="s1" value="Morning">
                                    <label for="Morning">Morning</label><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-field col m6 s12" id="afternoon" style="display: none">
                                    <input type="radio" id="Afternoon" name="s1" value="Afternoon">
                                    <label for="Afternoon">Afternoon</label><br>
                                </div>
```

I don't know why is this happening , the radio button data is not inserted to the MySQL database

Comment: Are you selecting any one of the radio button? Because you have "display:none" of both div that has a radio button.

Comment: And where is your form? How you're getting it as POST? Provide complete code of your form.

Comment: yes , i use javascript to show the radio button when it is needed

Comment: And if it is not needed then you do not send it in POST right?

Comment: Well i did sent it in POST even though it's not needed, The data will be blank if it's not needed

Comment: All of the data can be inserted into the database except the radio button s1

Comment: Before insert query try echo $s1 whether it has a value coming from form or not.